# CP dashboard is not visible for users

Tags: devdemon-forms

The CP Dashboard from the Forms Module is only visible for de admin. I would like to make it visible for a member group. The member group can access the module but they don't see the dashboard on de CP home page.

Answer (score 0):

Double check to see if you have an options setting under the 'Accessories' group for Forms. If so, try setting access there. You should also be able to set the permissed groups under the member group permissions settings. It would help knowing what version of EE and what version of Forms you are using.